# How we can change unicorns eating daisies?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Going to [tour](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tour) page, it has fictive question and answer.

How this can be changed to some more practical examples?

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Unicorns are not related to the site. [Other SE](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) sites has it right. It indicates that unicorns are a good questions.

Comment: My sense of humour informs me that this is a better example question than some boring question about Vim. I am not particuarly worried that some poor soul will be so utterly confused by this that he or she will ask questions about Unicorns on this site... Other than that, all remaining discussion on this topic is a [bikeshed](http://bikeshed.org/) :-)

Comment: There are other sections we need to go out as well and I think only the (diamond) moderators can edit them. Once SE select the pro temp moderators, we can go about fixing them.

Comment: FYI, a question has now been selected. I still prefer the Unicorn questions though ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for letting me know. We can always ask moderators to change it as Rob suggested.

Comment: @MartinTournoij and now we're back to unicorns. :D

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but I think I manually changed/reset that at some point @muru, as I don't think that [the only eligible question is a very good example](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2455/51), as the top answer is omitted in the example output, giving a rather "meh" example answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not yet.

> There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page

If I am reading the database query correctly, the sample question must meet the following criteria before it can be selected:

- Open and owned by a user (i.e. not anonymous or community wiki)
- Score >= 5
- Length <= 400
- Contains at least two answers with score >= 1 and at least one comment each
- Questions and answers must *not* contain any lists, block quotes, code, images, or header formatting in the body

This is a new site, so there are no eligible questions yet. I believe the system will pick a question as soon as it meets the criteria, but if not, the moderators will have a function to select one from your site just as soon as one becomes eligible.

Comment: It's kinda ironic that Ask Ubuntu's sample question is "How to copy paste contents in VI editor?". Does the sample question change? (Say, random shuffling between eligible posts?)

Comment: @muru The question does not change unless manually changed by a moderator.