# Tour page sample question

Tags: discussion

As of right now, we are still using the [unicorns eating daisies](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/how-we-can-change-unicorns-eating-daisies) page on the [tour](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tour).

The only available question we have to replace it with is [What additional features do gVim and/or MacVim offer compared to Vim inside a terminal emulator?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2455/10604)
.

I would like to see our tour have a more related question than unicorns & daisies, but I don't want to override that if that the community doesn't like the above candidate.

Please vote/respond with your opinions; my goal is to reach some kind of consensus.

Comment: I think I reset it at some point because I felt that was a rather poor example question, and the "unicorns eating daisies" one is at least somewhat amusing. There are some criteria regarding question/answer length etc. are pretty strict. [Previous comment](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/how-we-can-change-unicorns-eating-daisies#comment1103_1222)